# What is mysql_fetch_assoc equivalant in ZF?

Tags: php, zend-framework

What is mysql_fetch_assoc equivalant in ZF?

Comment: fetchRow in the Db adapter...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several possibilities

using a plain db adapter, [reference](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.select.fetchassoc):

```
$db->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $db->fetchRow('SELECT * FROM bugs WHERE bug_id = 2');

// also works
$result = $db->fetchRow('SELECT * FROM bugs WHERE bug_id = 2', array(), Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC);

// note that $result is a single object, not an array of objects
echo $result['bug_description'];
```

using a table class, [reference](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.fetch-row)

```
$table = new Bugs();

$select  = $table->select()->where('bug_status = ?', 'NEW')
                           ->order('bug_id');

$row = $table->fetchRow($select);
$rowArray = $row->toArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
$table->fetchRow($select)->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have initialized a database connection, you can request it by

`$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();`

Now you can use the db adapter to query your results, and get it with `mysql_fetch_assoc`

**using Zend_Select**

```
$select = $db->select()
             ->from('table')
             ->where('id = ?', 5);

// mysql_fetch_assoc
$row = $db->fetchRow($select);
print_r($row);
```

**Using manual SQL query**

```
// mysql_fetch_assoc
$row = $db->fetchRow("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 5");
print_r($row);
```

**Fetching multiple rows**

use fetchAll method, which will return a assoc array with the results.

```
 $db->fetchAll( "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC );
```